# Mount only specific USB stick

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, mount, restrictions

I am trying to configure a Linux (Ubuntu 14.10) so that it will only mount a specific USB stick from one specific USB port.

Can someone point me into the right direction on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/udev/local.rules` file on my system looks like:

```
...
# Media automounting
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="add"    RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ACTION=="remove" RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh"
...
```

I suppose you have something similar.

If you need to allow automount of a single specific USB stick (or a limited number of known sticks), you can add `ATTRS{serial}=="SERIAL"` to the `add` rule, repeating it for each stick you want to automount.

If a more advanced logic is necessary, you could modify the `/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh` script itself. I use it to specify specific mount options to some of the partitions on my removable drives.